# How should I store unique stats on multiple links?

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

I'm working on a link shortener project in php, and I would like to be able to record unique stats for every link by storing the visiter's IP. This I figure can be accomplished easily using a MYSQL database to store an ips for a single link, however over hundreds or possibliy thousands of links I will end up with a huge number of tables in my database.

Would it be more efficient or, better practice, to create a text file for each link and just store each unique hashed IP in that file?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why not store them all in a single table? Use a two field key based on IP address and link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with 2 DB tables, as follow:

```
Table 'link'
- id (AUTO INC)
- link (STRING)

Table 'visit'
- id (AUTO INC)
- link_id (FK)
- ip (STRING)
- count (INT)
```

If a user comes back twice to the same page, you can use a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` type of query to increment the count instead of setting it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just logging information then writing to file will be quicker. Writing to the database still has to write but you are also running the database engine.

If you want to audit the data outside of scrolling the file, then MySQL would be a better route.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a huge number of tables.  You only need 2 tables.  One will store the list of links, and then another table with a foreign key from the links table and the other data you want to capture.

Answer (score 0):

In the long run using a database will be much better as it organizes the data and lets you query it. Otherwise you may have the data in your logs but you won't be able to do anything with that data...